# How I get data from model field and calculate with data from template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

hello I am new in django and I have some questions (I do not speek english so good ,sorry)

I want to recive data from the template (input element)
and calculate this with model data field.

for exemple I have money_for_month = 1000$ in model field.
and the input from the user is "3" (e.g. 3 month) so I want the result to be 3000$ store it in a variable and display it bellow the input element.

if someone can help. thanks.

this is my models

```
class Mitnadv(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    money_for_month = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
```

and this is my view

```
class MitnadvDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Mitnadv
    template_name = "mit_app/mitnadv-detail.html"
    context_object_name = "mit"
    list_var = {}

    def post(self,request, **kwargs):
        num_m = request.POST["num-month"]
        self.list_var["num_month"] = num_m
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

and this is my template

```
  <h2>pay for x mounth</h2>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="number" name="num-month">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this method within the class and implement your needs.

```
def post(self,request, **kwargs):
    obj = MyModel.objects.get()
    money_for_month = obj.money_for_month
    num = request.POST.get('num-month', 0) % 0 is the default value if the num-month doesn't exist
    result = int(money_for_month) * int(num)

    return render(request, 'mit_app/mitnadv-detail.html', {'data': result})
```

Comment: @yohai you're welcome, please don't forget ticking this answer.